# How to launch app in CarPlay Dashboard after click CPDashboardButton in CPDashboardController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, scenekit, carplay

I have navigation app and now I'm developing CarPlay Dashboard. I can't launch InterfaceController after click button in CPDashboard.

[image]

My button code:

```
let searchButton = CPDashboardButton(titleVariants: ["Find"], subtitleVariants: ["place"], image: searchImage) { [weak self] (_) in
                self?.openSearchView()
            }
```

After button tap, func openSearchView() is called, but view still stay in dashboard.

There is no info in docs, how can we switch between view (interface controller <-> dashboard controller)

Comment: Hello Michael, can you me with this issue? I’m trying the same, so opening the main template application when the button is pressed, but I cannot figure out how to open the scene. My questions are:
what is the URL to open?
on which scene should I call the open function?
when code reaches the scene how do I open the scene to show on the screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure this is the right way, but ther is no mention about this, not even the official sample app does it. But you can achieve it by calling `open(_, options:, completionHandler)` on dashboardScene.

Like this

```
dashboardController.shortcutButtons = [CPDashboardButton(titleVariants: ["Find"], subtitleVariants: ["place"], image: searchImage, handler: { _ in
    guard let url = URL(string: "your.app.scheme://whatever/wherever") else { return }
    templateApplicationDashboardScene.open(url, options: nil, completionHandler: nil)
})]
```

This will open the main app and calls `open(_, urlContexts:)` on main carplay scene where you can handle that url and react accordingly, like open search ar whatever.

Comment: That's it! I did it 3 weeks ago, and forgot write answer here. Thanks for your help ;)

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue. However, it does not work for me when using the .open() function. I wrote "my.app.scheme://carplay". That might be the issue? Should it be something specific that I don't know about?

And if there is another way, that would be really helpful.

"my.app.scheme" being my actual app scheme 

Answer (score 1):

### For a more detailed answer:

1. Create your `CPDashboardButton` and add a handler.

Something like this:

```
let searchButton = CPDashboardButton(titleVariants: ["Search"], subtitleVariants: [], image: UIImage(named: "search_icon")!) { [weak self] _ in
    self?.searchTemplateManager.showSearchInterface() // You can do anything here. I have a manager that shows the search interface on the main CPTemplateApplicationScene.
    guard let dashboardScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first(where: { $0 is CPTemplateApplicationDashboardScene }) else { return }
    guard let url = URL(string: "someRandomUrl://") else { return }
    dashboardScene.open(url, options: .none, completionHandler: nil)
}
```

**Note** that you have to find the `CPTemplateApplicationDashboardScene` among your `UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes` and call `open()` on it.

2. Register the URL you are trying to open (`"someRandomUrl://"` in this example) as a URL Scheme in URL Types.

- Select your app's target and go to the "Info" tab.
- Expand the "URL Types" section. If it's not there, you may need to add it by clicking on the "+" button.
- Add a new URL type and specify a unique scheme. This is usually your app's name or something relevant to your app.

[image]

3. Register the URL Scheme in Info.plist
   In `Queried URL Schemes` array add your URL Scheme, `someRandomUrl` in this example.

[image]

After this the main `CPTemplateApplicationScene` will open when pressing the button.

4. In case you want to customise how you react to the URL you can add a suffix to the URL when you call it. E.g.:

```
guard let url = URL(string: "someRandomUrl://some-task-to-do") else { return }
```

Then catch the URL opening action in your `SceneDelegate`. You have to do this on the same class that is a delegate for `CPTemplateApplicationDashboardSceneDelegate` as you're opening an URL there.

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {
    guard let url = URLContexts.first?.url else { return }
    print("the url is: \(url)")
}
```

This prints: "*the url is: someRandomUrl://some-task-to-do*" where you can extract the suffix and switch on it to act accordingly.