# Open CarPlay main application when tapping dashboard shortcut button

Tags: ios, swift, navigation, mapkit, carplay

I am creating a turn-by-turn navigation app for CarPlay. I have two shortcut buttons on the dashboard view. When tapping one of the buttons, I expect the screen to transition into the "main" app. However, what happens is: It runs the code behind the scenes (search for either food or fuel) and it displays the search results, but you can only see them if you manually tap on the map or the app icon.

My code looks like this:

```
func initializeDashboardButtons() {
        if let image1 = UIImage(systemName: "fuelpump"), let image2 = UIImage(systemName: "fork.knife") {
            let button1 = CPDashboardButton(titleVariants: [defaultFuel], subtitleVariants: [], image: image1, handler: { [weak self] _ in self?.navigateToGasStations() })
            let button2 = CPDashboardButton(titleVariants: [defaultFood], subtitleVariants: [], image: image2, handler: { [weak self] _ in self?.navigateToFood() })
            self.dashboardController?.shortcutButtons = [button1, button2]
        }
    }
```

```
private func navigateToGasStations() {
    self.carplayManager.searchForLocation(locationText: defaultFuel, completionHandler: { [weak self] destinations in self?.handleSearchResult(results: destinations) })
}

private func navigateToFood() {
    self.carplayManager.searchForLocation(locationText: defaultFood, completionHandler: { [weak self] destinations in self?.handleSearchResult(results: destinations) })
}

private func handleSearchResult(results: [Destination]) {
    self.defaultAction?(results.convertToCPListItem(), "")
}
```

My goal is to open the main app, when one of the two buttons it tapped.

Thanks in advance.

I have tried to look at Apples sample app, where they also have shortcut buttons. However their sample app does not transition into the main app either. I can see that Google can do it with their Maps app, so there must be a way. I just haven't found it in the documentation.

I also looked at this question/answer, but it does not work for me.
[How to launch app in CarPlay Dashboard after click CPDashboardButton in CPDashboardController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66347904/how-to-launch-app-in-carplay-dashboard-after-click-cpdashboardbutton-in-cpdashbo)

Comment: Hi, have you found an answer for this? I'm struggling with it right now.

Comment: Hi, yes. The answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66347904/how-to-launch-app-in-carplay-dashboard-after-click-cpdashboardbutton-in-cpdashbo was actually the right one. The scheme is just the apps name. 

I am doping this: guard let url = URL(string: "APP_NAME://") else { return }
            self.scene?.open(url, options: .none, completionHandler: nil)

Comment: Thanks, but my issue was that this calls the SceneDelegate's scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) function, and does not show the TemplateApplicationScene of the CarPlay. So how can I launch the scene?

Answer (score 0):

### Opening the main CPTemplateApplicationScene:

1. Create your `CPDashboardButton` and add a handler.

Something like this:

```
let searchButton = CPDashboardButton(titleVariants: ["Search"], subtitleVariants: [], image: UIImage(named: "search_icon")!) { [weak self] _ in
    self?.searchTemplateManager.showSearchInterface() // You can do anything here. I have a manager that shows the search interface on the main CPTemplateApplicationScene.
    guard let dashboardScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first(where: { $0 is CPTemplateApplicationDashboardScene }) else { return }
    guard let url = URL(string: "someRandomUrl://") else { return }
    dashboardScene.open(url, options: .none, completionHandler: nil)
}
```

**Note** that you have to find the `CPTemplateApplicationDashboardScene` among your `UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes` and call `open()` on it.

2. Register the URL you are trying to open (`"someRandomUrl://"` in this example) as a URL Scheme in URL Types.

- Select your app's target and go to the "Info" tab.
- Expand the "URL Types" section. If it's not there, you may need to add it by clicking on the "+" button.
- Add a new URL type and specify a unique scheme. This is usually your app's name or something relevant to your app.

[image]

3. Register the URL Scheme in Info.plist
   In `Queried URL Schemes` array add your URL Scheme, `someRandomUrl` in this example.

[image]

After this the main `CPTemplateApplicationScene` will open when pressing the button.

4. In case you want to customise how you react to the URL you can add a suffix to the URL when you call it. E.g.:

```
guard let url = URL(string: "someRandomUrl://some-task-to-do") else { return }
```

Then catch the URL opening action in your `SceneDelegate`. You have to do this on the same class that is a delegate for `CPTemplateApplicationDashboardSceneDelegate` as you're opening an URL there.

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {
    guard let url = URLContexts.first?.url else { return }
    print("the url is: \(url)")
}
```

This prints: "*the url is: someRandomUrl://some-task-to-do*" where you can extract the suffix and switch on it to act accordingly.